# I dont know how to do error handling with incorrect inputs

Tags: python, error-handling

im trying to make it so in a part of my code where a user enters their name that they cant enter a number, without the program crashing. I am also trying to do the same with some other parts of my code aswell

I havent tried anything as of now

```
enter code here
myName = str(input('Hello! What is your name?')) #Asks the user to input their name
myName = str(myName.capitalize()) #Capitalises the first letter of their name if not already



level = int(input('Please select a level between 1 and 3. 1 being the easiest and 3 being the hardest'))




guessNumber()
print('')
print('It is recommended to pick a harder level if you chose to progress')
print('')
again = int(input("Would you like to play again? Input 1 for yes or 2 for no?" ))


# Is asking the user if they want to play again.

if again == 1: 
    guessNumber()


if again == 2:
    print('Thanks for playing Guessing Game :)')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code of `guessNumber()`.

kinda difficult to understand question anyway I'd do this.

To accept a `string` and if the value entered is `int` it'd give the message but you can't differentiate as `int` cant be `str` but `str` can be a number.

```
try:
   myName=str(input("Enter name\n"))
except ValueError as okok:
   print("Please Enter proper value")
else:
   printvalue=f"{myName}"
   print(printvalue)
```